# how to disable Flash as2 button keyPress "<Right>"

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2

I am trying to disable a button keyPress **Right** command just after it was pressed but until now I didn't succeed.

On the button I have:

```
on(press, keyPress "<Right>" ){
    myFunction();
}
```

Inside 'myFunction' among a lot of stuff I have:

```
some_bt.enabled = false; //it is working fine with mouse action!
```

The thing is this works only when user hits 'some_bt' with mouse, but **not** when he hit **Right** arrow. In many cases some users spam the **Right** and this messes up my code.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, haven't seen this "on(press)" code since like 10 years :) You need to assign a function with the onRelease method. Not sure about the exact syntax in AS2 but it was something like:

```
// add a function to be called on release
some_bt.onRelease = myFunction;

myFunction = function()
{
   // do your stuff here

   // remove the onRelease callback
   some_bt.onRelease = null;
}
```

For the right key you might listen for all keyboard events and disable it when done:

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() 
{
   if(Key.getCode() == Key.RIGHT)
   {
       myFunction();
   }
};
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

and inside your myFunction:

```
Key.removeListener(keyListener);
```

Comment: We have some reasons here to keep using AS2, so I cannot take the approach you told me since it is an AS3 solution.